# web based video chat similar to gmail chat/video chat

Tags: video, chat

i m developing a social networking application using php and i want to make a chat application which supports video chat features like in Gmail ( google provides browser plugin for that )

I have checked tokbox. but I would like to see some real/sample sites(like meebo) using tokbox for video chat.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps this will get you started, and on the correct path. From here, you can revisit Stackoverflow with specific questions about particular steps you take along the way.

<strike>Adobe.com » [Creating a Video Chat: Your First Macromedia Flash Communication Server MX Application](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashcom/articles/first_comm_app.html)</strike>

Wayback: [Creating a Video Chat: Your First Macromedia Flash Communication Server MX Application](http://web.archive.org/web/20080714101040/http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashcom/articles/first_comm_app.html)

Comment: @Henrik Thank you. I managed to find this on the Wayback Archive.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect Subramanian has already found their solution.  I'm curious what he or she found to do to accomplish this engineering feat????

Recently (2011):  Openfire chat with its various software plugins & clients are the best open source solution.  Voice and Video chat are handled almost entirely directly via a peer-to-peer connection.  The server is only required to "point" client IPs as they traverse to find each other.  Read about STUN & TURN servers.  This is also how the iPhone "Facetime" video chat works.  It's a complicated seteup and some pretty rough C++ libraries.

Voice and Video chat remain right at the edge of Open Source availability.  You can get there today (FALL 2012) but it takes a good deal of skill to understand and wire-up all that is required.  Every day it will get easier however and someday soon it will be simple RPMs (& .DEB:) installations.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that videochat requires some sort of streaming server in the host-environment, dont think you can do that with PHP alone.

It might be more usefull to look for some videostreaming server software.

Hope this helps you on in your search?